# DateFormat issue

Tags: java, date-format

This code is always throwing a parse expection

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2011-10-28T17:06:03.046Z".
```

I'm using 1.6.0_24 java ver.

```
SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.US);
            try {
                utilDate = inFormat.parse("2011-10-28T17:06:03.046Z");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                utilDate = null;
            }
```

Can you point me to the error?

Answer (score 3):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
Says:
`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" -> 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700`
So put `Z` into `'` and it should work or leave out the `Z` completely:

```
SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);   
try { utilDate = inFormat.parse("2011-10-28T17:06:03.046"); } catch (ParseException e) {   utilDate = null; }
```

or

```
SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US);   
try { utilDate = inFormat.parse("2011-10-28T17:06:03.046Z"); } catch (ParseException e) {   utilDate = null; }
```

Comment: This works like a charm... Thanks for quick response.SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US);   
try { utilDate = inFormat.parse("2011-10-28T17:06:03.046Z"); } catch (ParseException e) {   utilDate = null; }

Comment: @Fildor Hi Fildor, in my code when i use "2012-10-30T09:30:10Z" It is working fine but for "2012-10-30T14:30:10Z"   (>12) Then i am getting "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException=cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '2012-8-30T14:30:10Z' is not a valid value for 'dateTime'". Could you please help me ??